# Failure parsing xml document coldfusion xmlSeach

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am trying to parse an xml document, but for some reason I keep coming up empty.  I haven't dealt with xml files whole lot, but the last project I did a bunch of xml processing, so I figured the same methods would work.

Here is the entire document: [xml File](http://pastebin.com/uUfLkEZS)

I am trying to extract the offer nodes out using `xmlSearch()`, in a cfc function(just started the project, so there is much here):

```
<cffunction name="getOffers" access="public">
    <cfargument name="theXML" type="xml" required="true" />

    <cfset var temp =  []>

    <cfset temp = xmlSearch(arguments.theXML, "ChromeResponse/OfferVehicles/OfferVehicle/Offers/Offer")>

</cffunction>
```

In this particular case, I would expect the array to contain two elements, but it is empty.  I have tried to everything combination, but nothing seems to be working for me.  I have a feeling it is something little that I'm not seeing, but I can't find it.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

---

Solution:

The xml didn't declare a namespace.

Comment: just as an fyi once you've declared your argument you can go straight to `<cfreturn xmlSearch(arguments.theXML,searchPath)>` you don't need to set 2 variables before returning the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a namespace declaration (or whatever the technical term is) in your root element, so you need to reflect that in your xpath string:

```
/:ChromeResponse/:OfferVehicles/:OfferVehicle/:Offers/:Offer
```

That returns your two records for me on CF9 & Railo 4.x (via [cflive.net](http://cflive.net)).

I *think* you might have problems on CF10 as I think its XML parser doesn't like namespace syntax without the actual namespace (eg: it won't like `:ChromeResponse`, expecting something like `namespacehere:ChromeResponse`.

You don't say which version of CF, so I don't know if that's relevant.

NB: you also are missing a closing parenthesis on your `xmlSearch()` call, but presume that's a typo.

Comment: I'm using CF9.  In the other xml project I mentioned, the namespace was "p", but this one didn't appear to have one.  Are you saying it does?

Comment: Your assumption about CF 10 is correct. Cannot seem to find a way to search the doc with the empty namespace.

Comment: This worked.  Thanks.We are transitioning to CF10, and from what I'm reading, the xml will be parse correctly when we do?  I'm thinking I should speak to the company providing the xml and see if they would considering adding a namespace.

Comment: Here is code that works with CF 10 (with the XML the way it is) for when you need it. `offers = xmlSearch(xml, "//*[local-name()='Offer' and namespace-uri()='http://api.chromedata.com/ChromeData-BestOffer-Response']");`

Comment: @ScottStroz  Thanks for the tip.  I'll put that in the production notes.

Comment: @ScottStroz / Rob, this is the bug ref in ColdFusion 10: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3377581. I'm not suggesting it's actually a bug: based on the comments in the ticket, empty namepspaces aren't actually legal. I don't - myself - know one way or the other, but I might investigate...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have do debug these I work my way deeper and deeper into the structure. try some something like

```
<cfset temp = xmlSearch(arguments.theXML, "ChromeResponse">

<cfset temp = xmlSearch(arguments.theXML, "ChromeResponse/OfferVehicles">

<cfset temp = xmlSearch(arguments.theXML, "ChromeResponse/OfferVehicles/OfferVehicle">

<cfset temp = xmlSearch(arguments.theXML, "ChromeResponse/OfferVehicles/OfferVehicle/Offers">
```

Comment: In ColdFusion 10, I am getting an empty array doing `xmlSearch(xml, "ChromeResponse")` or `xmlSearch(xml, "/ChromeResponse")` or `xmlSearch(xml, "//ChromeResponse")` using the XML provided in the link.

Comment: @ScottStroz the xml hasn't been filtered at all. That is the xml that I am currently working with, and at least you are experiencing the same issue as me.